# UnsafeRawPointer to UnsafeMutableRawPointer

Tags: ios, flutter, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I'm in the process of creating a Flutter plugin which wraps [Google Ml Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides) for barcode scanning.

Right now I'm trying to convert [this piece of code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/54c2e626641a584091b36efe26dbe37d6383f45b/packages/firebase_ml_vision/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMlVisionPlugin.m#L164) to swift in order to scan an array of bytes which come from the Dart side so I can process it with the [barcode scanner](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios) feature.

[This is my current implementation.](https://github.com/svprdga/ML-Kit-Barcode-Scanner/blob/5c0c56fc617d08c74d497857e052cb9e5f2805cb/ios/Classes/SwiftMlKitBarcodeScannerPlugin.swift#L76) I am getting the following error:

> ```
> 9:101: error: cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type
> 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer'
>             let pixelBuffer = createPixelBufferFromBytes(width: width!, height:height!, data:  data.bytes,
>             bytes: planes![0]["bytes"] as! Int)
> ```

So I guess that I have to convert an UnsafeRawPointer to an UnsafeMutableRawPointer.

So, how can I safely do this conversion?

Comment: did you find the Solution ?

Comment: No @SkandarMunir, I've abandoned the project.

Comment: Ohoo, Don't abandon it. I've found a Solution and Implemented it. Works Great. Let me Share Sample Code.

Answer (score 0):

I Understand you have Implemented the channel calls and good till Converting bytes and Planes into UIImage. But I've noticed there isn't much work done on:

**Image regeneration in Swift from Flutter Image Stream.**

So if Someone Come Accross Same Issue I am adding all Steps at SWIFT End.

> Step 1:
> Receive Param via Channle Call in Swift

```
guard let args = call.arguments else {
                result("iOS could not recognize flutter arguments in method: (yourFuncName)")
                return
            }
```

> Step 2: From Dictionary Extract 4 Important values required for Image
> regeneration.

```
let params: [String : Any] = args as! [String : Any] 

let imageData: [String : Any] = params["imageData"] as! [String : Any]
```

> Step 3: Pass imageData to  UIImageFromImageData as NSDictionary

```
 guard let image = UIImageFromImageData(imageData: imageData as NSDictionary ) else { return }
```

> UIImageFromImageData:

```
  func UIImageFromImageData(imageData: NSDictionary) -> UIImage? {

            if(imageData.count > 0)
            {
            return bytesToImage(imageData: imageData)!;
            }else
            {
                return nil
            }
    }
```

> bytesToImage

```
 func bytesToImage(imageData: [String : Any]) -> UIImage?{
        
          let imgD: FlutterStandardTypedData? = imageData["bytes"] as? FlutterStandardTypedData
        let imageBytes : Data
        imageBytes = imgD!.data
            
           let metadata: [String : Any] = imageData["metadata"] as! [String : Any]
    
           let planeData = metadata["planeData"] as! Array<Any>
           let planeCount = planeData.count
    
           let width = metadata["width"] as! Int
           let height = metadata["height"] as! Int
    
    
           let rawFormat = metadata["imageFormat"] as! NSNumber
            
        let pxBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?;

            if(planeCount==0)
            {
                //Throw Exception planes should be greated than Zero
                return nil
            }
            else if (planeCount==1)
            {
                let plane: [String : Any] = planeData[0] as! [String : Any]
                let bytesPerRow = plane["bytesPerRow"] as! Int
                let bytesData : UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer
                let nsData = imageBytes as NSData
                let rawPtr = nsData.bytes
                let b:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating:rawPtr)
                
                pxBuffer =  bytesToPixelBuffer(width: width, height: height, format: rawFormat, baseAddress: b, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow)
                if pxBuffer != nil {
                    return UIImage(cgImage: pxBufferToCGImage(pixelBuffer: pxBuffer!)!)
                }
else
{
return
}
                
            }
            else
            {
              pxBuffer = planarBytesToPixelBuffer()
            }
        
        return UIImage()
    }
```

> bytesToPixelBuffer

```
 func bytesToPixelBuffer(width: Int, height: Int, format: FourCharCode,baseAddress : UnsafeMutableRawPointer, bytesPerRow: Int) -> CVBuffer?{
        var dstPixelBuffer: CVBuffer?
        // Format is very Important use Same Format to regenerate buffer as you were using in Flutter Side I would recommend 1111970369 Raw format.

         CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, format, baseAddress, bytesPerRow,
                                                nil, nil, nil, &dstPixelBuffer)
        return dstPixelBuffer ?? nil

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat your answer. If there was something about your previous answer you wanted to change, you should have edited it.